# Designing URLs in URLconf

Tags: python, django

while developing web app using Django, why is URLconf required? I'm trying to create one for a web app, and I can't understand how is it written. :(

I got this URLconf example from djangoproject.com. Would anyone help me interpret how the patterns are written here? What are (\d{4}), (\d{2}) and (\d+)/ ?

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
)
```

Comment: If you want your application to recognize URLs, you need a urlconf. Naturally, this is explained fully in the tutorial, which you should read before asking questions here.

Comment: there is no explanation in the tutorial regarding what is d{4}. if you carefully see the above code snippet, you can notice the code is taken from the tutorial itself. why would anyone ask a question about it if it was explained there at the tutorial itself?

Answer (score 1):

Django URL patterns are actually python regular expressions. `\d{4}` means 4 digits. `\d+` means at least one (or more) digits. [Here's a quick intro](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) to the subject.